# Why is my Regex for removing special characters adding more words to my text?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, regex, text

I encountered the problem when I tired to run my regex function on my text which can be found [here](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/45839/45839.txt).

With a HttpRequest I fetch the text form the link above. Then I run my regex to clean up the text before filtering the most occurrences of a certain word.

After cleaning up the word I split the string by whitespace and added it into a string array and notice there was a huge difference in the number of indexes.

Does anyone know why this happens because the result of occurrences for the word " the " - is 6806 hits.
[raw data correct answer is 6806](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9l9fT.png)

And with my regex I get - 8073 hits

[with regex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Im9m8.png)

The regex i'm using is [here in the sandbox with the text](https://regex101.com/r/8KfL6F/1) and below in the code.

````
//Application storing.
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, long>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

// Cleaning up a bit
var words = CleanByRegex(rawSource);

string[] arr = words.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

string CleanByRegex(string rawSource)
{
    Regex r = RemoveSpecialChars();
    return r.Replace(rawSource, " ");
}

//  arr {string[220980]} - with regex
//  arr {string[157594]} - without regex

foreach (var word in arr)
{
    // some logic

}


```
partial class Program
{
    [GeneratedRegex("(?:[^a-zA-Z0-9]|(?<=['\\\"]\\s))", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled, "en-SE")]
    private static partial Regex RemoveSpecialChars();
}
```
````

I have tried debugging it and I have my suspicion  that I'm adding trailing whitespace but I don't know how to handle it.

I have tired to add a whitespace removing regex where I remove multiple whitespace and replace that with one whitespace.

the regex would look something like - `[ ]{2,}"`

```
partial class Program
{
    [GeneratedRegex("[ ]{2,}", RegexOptions.Compiled)]
    private static partial Regex RemoveWhiteSpaceTrails();
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're using .NET 6+ Roslyn code-gen for Regexes? I suggest you go back to using `Regex` the _traditional_ way for now, as that's more well-understood and there's more resources available about it.

Comment: The results for Multiline/SingleLine may be different.  I've seen cases where Regex uses the last setting for Multiline/Singleline.

Comment: @jdweng I don't understand what you mean by "uses the last setting for multi/single line.

Comment: A previous time the Regex class was used.  It may be a static parameter

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you describe what you're trying to clean up.
However your specific question is answerable: from the [sandbox](https://regex101.com/r/8KfL6F/1) I see that you're removing newlines and punctuation. This can definitely lead to occurrences of `the`  that weren't there before:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the
lazy dog
//the+newline does not match

//after regex:
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
//now there's one more *the+space*
```

If you change your search to something not so common, for example `Seward`, then you should see the same results before and after the regex.

Comment: To try out my code I added a basic lorem Ipsum text. Because the search on chrome is not really the correct answer because if I was to search for " the " that would mean i won't get the the+new.Line or All the sentences that begins with "The ". 



Since I am curious about the words in the Text I used the following regex ```\w+``` to get the words and returned a MatchCollection. That i later looped through to add the value to my dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The reason I believe the regex created more text while I was replacing it with string.empty or `" "`. Is not true I just created more matches.

Is because I thought the search in Chrome via `ctrl + f` would give me all the words for a certain search and this necessarily isn't true.

I tried my code and instead I added a subset of the Lorem Ipsum text. This is because I questioned the search on Chrome to see if it's really the correct answer.

Short answer is NO.

If I was to search for " the " that would mean I won't get the `"the+Environmental.NewLine"` which **@simmetric** proved,

Another scenario is sentences that begins with the word `"The "`. Since I am curious about the words in the Text I used the following regex `\w+` to get the words and returned a MatchCollection `(IList<Match>())` That I later looped through to add the value to my dictionary.

Code Demonstration

```
var rawSource = "Some text"
var words = CleanByRegex(rawSource);

IList<Match> CleanByRegex(string rawSource)
{
    IList<Match> r = Regex.Matches(rawSource, "\\w+");
    return r;
}

foreach (var word in words)
{
    
    if (word.Value.Length >= 1) // at least 3 letters and has any letters
    {
        if (dictionary.ContainsKey(word.Value)) //if it's in the dictionary
            dictionary[word.Value] = dictionary[word.Value] + 1; //Increment the count
        else
            dictionary[word.Value] = 1; //put it in the dictionary with a count 1
    }
}
```

Comment: You say it 'created more text' but I don't believe that's the case. What it does is create more matches with your search string, it doesn't make the input text any longer.